# can't post json to php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using this code to post to a php page. Why am I not receiving the post data on server side?

```
$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost/contact.php',
          data: JSON.stringify( { "first_name": fname, "last_name": lname, "email": email, "phone_number":phone } ),
          processData: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            }).success(function (html) {alert(html);});
```

php code

```
<?php
echo $_POST["first_name"];
//echo $id;

?>
```

Comment: How exactly are you *trying* to receive that data...!?

Comment: Why are you posting json? Just make an ordinary POST request, and it will work

Comment: Could you add the PHP code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON get posted as A Raw HTTP Post Data without any Query String and will not be Saved into $_POST global Variable so you will have to fetch the Raw Data with another way like this:

```
$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Get Raw Posted Data
$json = json_decode($post_data, true); // Decode it
```